# Unable to set Executable permissions in Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage Bucket(Standard variant) and a Compute engine instance(Debian Stretch 9) in my GCP (both are under the same project and have all the permissions since I am the owner of the project).

I have created a storage bucket and successfully authenticated and mounted the storage bucket in my Linux Machine. I am able to read | Write and Delete the files from my Linux machine as well as from the WebUI.

Now the problem is I am unable to set files to executable form both from normal user and using sudo before chmod.
[Sudo User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8rLP.png) and [normal user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHMlD.png)

I have also tried making it executable with root but the root user is not allowed to get access to the folder where I have mounted my bucket.
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8GrJ.png)

I want to run my [Storj](https://storj.io) node in my Storage Bucket, therefore I need read write execute permissions.
Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since in Google Cloud Storage there is no execution flag defined, therefore we cannot execute files in the cloud storage.
So as such this question problem cannot be solved from the client-side.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZCLZ.png) to see the results.